# Torch7 - not enough memory: you tried to allocate 0GB. Buy new RAM

Tags: lua, torch

I tried to load a large audio dataset and implement audio.spectrogram.

I got this error:

```
$ Torch: not enough memory: you tried to allocate 0GB. Buy new RAM! at /home/XXXX/torch/pkg/torch/lib/TH/THGeneral.c:222
stack traceback:
[C]: at 0xb732c560
[C]: in function '__add'
/home/XXXX/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/audio/init.lua:107: in function 'spectrogram'
large.lua:24: in main chunk
[C]: in function 'dofile'
[string "_RESULT={dofile "large.lua"}"]:1: in main chunk
[C]: in function 'xpcall'
/home/XXXX/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/trepl/init.lua:650: in function 'repl'
...XX/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/trepl/scm-1/bin/th:199: in main chunk
[C]: at 0x0804d6d0
```

Does torch7 have the memory limit ?

Answer (score 2):

**No**, Torch does not have a memory limit but it requires that certain conditions are met when allocating memory.

If you take a look at [`THGeneral.c`](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/3864f3782a74715e35d98176f9014a74524a868a/lib/TH/THGeneral.c#L226-L273) (where the error comes from), you'll see that this error is raised when the allocation using `THAllocInternal` has failed.  From your output I guess you are on a Unix system and I also guess that you are trying to allocate a lot of memory (but less than 1GB).  In the case where you want to align more than 5120 bytes, `THAllocInternal` will call [`posix_memalign`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/posix_memalign.3.html) for 64 byte aligned memory otherwise it will call standard [`malloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc).  That is to say that the error you see comes from either of those functions which are provided by your operating system.  You will have to check there.  You could also try to recompile Torch with the flag `DISABLE_POSIX_MEMALIGN` to rule that out.

Answer (score 0):

You may have created a CNN model using PyTorch which runs on CUDA automatically if your system has a GPU. **Restart** the system, the memory will be cleared automatically.